# Cross-tab Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, crosstab

I have a table with employee attendance - lets say - OATT. Following is the structure and sample data

```
AttDate EmpId EmpName AttCode InTime OutTime
01-10-2009 1 Jain, Rahul P 0900 1830
02-10-2009 1 Jain, Rahul P 0900 1830
03-10-2009 1 Jain, Rahul P 0900 1830
04-10-2009 1 Jain, Rahul P 0900 1830
05-10-2009 1 Jain, Rahul P 0900 1830
06-10-2009 1 Jain, Rahul WO 0900 1830
07-10-2009 1 Jain, Rahul WO 0900 1830
08-10-2009 1 Jain, Rahul P 0900 1830
09-10-2009 1 Jain, Rahul L 0900 1830
10-10-2009 1 Jain, Rahul P 0900 1830
01-10-2009 1 Jain, Rahul A 0900 1830
```

I need the following result:

```
EmpId 01-10 02-10 03-10 04-10 05-10
1 P P P P P
2 P P P L P
3 P P P P A
```

I know that this can be accomplished using pivot queries, but I need a dynamic query to do it for a specified range of dates. I am using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

The PIVOT keyword might help, but even with that you still need to know what your columns are before running the query.  That usually means running two queries: one to get a list of columns names and then a second to actually get your results.

Comment: The columns are the dates. So, if the date range is 1-Oct-09 to 30-Oct-09, there should be one column for each date.

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  But Sql Server can't pick out your starting and ending points for you automatically.  You have to list each one out in your query, and it's particular tricky with dates.

Answer (score -1):

One of solution is that make Query to print out TSQL code into variable 
and after that to call exec @variable